# How to conditionally run GitHub Actions workflow job

Tags: devops, github-actions, cicd

After GitHub will now soon remove support for `save-state` and `set-output`, the following workflow logic will not work anymore:

```yaml
      - id: should_run
        continue-on-error: true
        name: check latest commit is less than 24 hours
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'schedule' }}
        run: test -z $(git rev-list  --after="24 hours"  ${{ github.sha }}) && echo "::set-output name=should_run::false"

  deploy:
    needs: check_date
    if: ${{ needs.check_date.outputs.should_run != 'false' }}
    name: Build container image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

As in the warning presented in the workflow run, environment files are the way to go. Although environment variables are easier to use and set up inside the job, they cannot be shared across multiple jobs as each job runs as a separate VM.

> The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon.
> Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see:
> https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/

Browsing through the GitHub community, I came across multiple recommendations of using `actions/upload-artifact` and `actions/download-artifact` to access the environment variable from one job inside the other.

It might be a valid solution for many use cases, but it does not do the trick for this one, as the second job would be required to run at least the `download-artifact` step for conditionally exiting the job run (following the [GitHub docs on storing workflow data](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#passing-data-between-jobs-in-a-workflow)).

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The URL in the deprecation message tells you exactly how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use both, it's just different syntax:

Instead of:

`echo "::set-output name=should_run::false"`

do this:

`echo "should_run=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`